# How to use Coq arithmetic solver tactics with SSReflect arithmetic statements

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

Coq has some convenient tactics for automatically proving arithmetic lemmas, for instance `lia`:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
From mathcomp Require Import ssrnat.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Require Import Psatz.

Lemma obv : forall (x y z: nat), (x < y)%coq_nat -> (y < z)%coq_nat -> (z < 3)%coq_nat -> (x < 3)%coq_nat.
Proof.
  move => x y z xlty yltz zlt3. lia.
Qed.
```

The tactics do not directly support SSReflect-style boolean reflection statements however:

```
Lemma obv_ssr: forall (x y z: nat), (x < y) && (y < z) && (z < 3) -> (x < 3).
Proof.
  move => x y z H.  Fail lia.
Abort.

Lemma obv_ssr: forall (x y z: nat), (x < y) -> (y < z) -> (z < 3) -> (x < 3).
Proof.
  move => x y z xlty yltz zlt3. Fail lia.
Abort.
```

It's possible to solve them by converting to non-SSR format using views:

```
Lemma obv_ssr: forall (x y z: nat), (x < y) && (y < z) && (z < 3) -> (x < 3).
Proof.
  move => x y z.  move/andP => [/andP [/ltP x_lt_y /ltP y_lt_z] /ltP z_lt_3].
  apply/ltP. lia.
Qed.
```

This is however very manual. Is there some kind of technique/approach/tactic that can automate this application of lemmas like `lia` to SSR-style statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet a totally resolved issue in general: you can track its progress [here](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/issues/263).

In your particular example the following is enough:

```
Lemma obv_ssr: forall (x y z: nat), (x < y) && (y < z) && (z < 3) -> (x < 3).
Proof.
move=> x y z.
rewrite -?(rwP andP) -?(rwP ltP).
lia.
Qed.
```

Sometimes you might want to throw in some more conversions of the standard arithmetic types using something like `rewrite -?plusE -?multE -?minusE` (adding more conversions if you have more arithmetic operations in your goal).

There are at least two projects trying to resolve the issue in general:

- https://github.com/amahboubi/lia4mathcomp (see [ssrnatlia](https://github.com/amahboubi/lia4mathcomp/blob/70182f813ee49f662365a1a3a5222ecec83c507b/lia_tactics.v#L227) tactic there, but I unless I'm mistaken it cannot solve your goal).
- https://github.com/pi8027/mczify -- an active project with a different architecture and as far as I know it should be capable of solving a lot of SSReflect-style goals.