# Coq error: Unable to unify "true" with "is_true (0 < a - b - 3)"

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic, formal-verification

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I thought `reflexivity` should work on below, but it does not.

```
a, b : nat
H : (1 <=? a - b - 3) = true
______________________________________(1/7)
is_true (0 < a - b - 3)
```

I also tried to `apply leb_complete in H.` which resulted in:

```
a, b : nat
H : (1 <= a - b - 3)%coq_nat
______________________________________(1/7)
is_true (0 < a - b - 3)
```

but in both cases, Coq gives me an error saying `Unable to unify "true" with "is_true (0 < a - b - 3)"`

It shouldn't be that complicated, right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add the imports?

Comment: @Blaisorblade, here it is 
```From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
Require Import String Arith Strings.Byte Init.Byte Init.Nat Coq.Lists.List Coq.Program.Wf.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, “it shouldn’t be complicated” is the wrong question.

`reflexivity` is a tactic that never uses assumptions, and that tries to prove goals in a very specific way. For “easy” purely numeric goals p, you can use lia.

It can only prove goals convertible to shape `R a1 a2` where R is a reflexive relation (like equality) and a1 and a2 are convertible. And two terms are convertible if reducing them to normal form gives “the same” result (modulo some complications for eta-expansion).

For instance, reflexivity can prove that 2 + 2 + 0 = 4, or that 0 + n = n. But it cannot prove that n + 0 = n (which can be proved by lia), because n + 0 is a normal form.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, by using `lia.`, Coq complains that `Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness.`

Comment: I solved the tactic failure issue I mentioned earlier by rewriting the goal as `rewrite -?(rwP ltP).` and then used `lia.`. For more information see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029979/how-to-use-coq-arithmetic-solver-tactics-with-ssreflect-arithmetic-statements 
So, I'm gonna accept this answer.